# pygame.midi.Input could not detect MIDI device

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, midi

I have this code

```
from pygame import midi
from time import 

midi.init()
midi_in = Input(-1)

while True:
    if not midi_in.pool(): break
    print(midi_in.read())
    time.sleep(.25)
```

In the `pygame.midi.Input` constructor (line #5) an exception was raised:

`pygame.midi.MidiException: 'Device id given is not a valid input id, it is an output id.'`

pygame raised an error because it could not find the MIDI Input Device?
But pygame.midi.get_device_info(device_id) returns:

- A valid result
- `1` is present at index 2 signifying that this device is an input device
- `0` is present at the last index of the result meaning that this device is closed

I am on pygame *2.1.2*, Python *3.10.0* and Windows *10* and
I have taken the following actions countless times:

- I have restarted my computer
- I have replugged the MIDI cables
- I have reinstalled Pygame

After doing all of this, I was expecting `pygame.midi` to function, but to no avail... It did not work.

**I am completly clueless!** Can anybody tell me how to fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: "pygame.midi.MidiException: 'Device id given is not a valid input id, it is an output id.'" Okay; so **what is unclear** about this message? It's clearly telling you about the code `midi_in = Input(-1)`, right? So. Did you **read the documentation** for `Input`, in order to understand what values should be used to call it? Does the value `-1` make sense there? Why? How did you decide to write `-1`, and not some other value? Was it based on reading the documentation? What do you think it should mean, and why?

Comment: "I have taken the following actions countless times:" As a **programmer** - not a computer user - these are the **last** things to try, because they mean that you're blaming someone else's code instead of your own. The **first** thing to try, when you get an error message, is to **read** the error message and **try to understand** it. "pygame raised an error because it could not find the MIDI Input Device?" I don't understand how you got this message from the error message that you quoted.

Comment: Note that `pygame.midi.get_default_input_id()` returns the default device ID or -1 if there are no devices. That strongly suggests that -1 is *not* a valid device number.

Comment: "But pygame.midi.get_device_info(device_id) returns:" There is nothing in the code that you show that says `pygame.midi.get_device_info(device_id)`, so there's no way we can explain the result you got from it. In particular, there is no way we can know what the value of `device_id` was when that code was run. Please read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: @RolandSmith advice about MIDI from someone named "Roland" seems auspicious :)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel its a shorthand for default input..... If you read the source file you whould know

Comment: Well, I know what the error message says, and it says differently, in very clear English.

Answer (score 0):

The argument of [`pygame.midi.Input`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/midi.html) is the device ID. You can get the default input device ID with [`pygame.midi.get_default_input_id`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/midi.html#pygame.midi.Input). e.g.:

```py
from pygame import midi
midi.init()

device_id = midi.get_default_input_id()
if device_id == -1:
    raise Exception('no midi input device found')

midi_in = midi.Input(device_id)
```

Comment: Yes, I did that but it did not work.

Comment: @codeforever10 What did not work? `midi.get_default_input_id()` or `midi.Input(device_id)`? Anyway it seams to be a problem with your system, but not with your code. We can't help you with your system. We can only answer questions about your code.